# List of wireless adapters that "just work" with Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, wireless

There are various resources out there, from the official [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported) to many forum topics and **Askubuntu** questions, all seeking to answer the same question: which adapters work with Ubuntu? But, as is usual in such situations, much of the existing material is messy and/or outdated.

I'd like to know which ones work with Ubuntu 11.10 specifically -- the latest, "out of the box" version, with no kernel modifications or additional drivers to manually mess with. I believe that this will be a very useful resource when deciding to buy an adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a list of Ubuntu-certified wireless chips at the Ubuntu website.
When you buy a product, make sure it features any of the listed chips.

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/WIRELESS

You may also find the following websites useful:

- http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers
- http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Devices/USB
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_wireless_drivers

Answer (score 3):

I bought this one [LM Technologies LM006 Wi-Fi USB Nano Adapter N](http://www.lm-technologies.com/adapters/LM006_Wi-Fi_USB_Nano_Adapter_N/) on someones recommendation that it "just works", and it does just that.

Comment: Link is not working

Comment: The link works for me.

Comment: works for me now too (was going to an amazon dead page before)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on Ubuntu or wireless adapters, and I was looking for the same information.  I bought a TP-Link TL-WN721N adapter, and it "just worked" with Ubuntu 11.10 (64 bit).  I didn't have to install anything, just plugged it in.

Comment: Same for me with TP-Link WN722NC, blogged about it here http://alicious.com/working-ubuntu-wifi-adapter/ (includes lsusb, iw list and similar output).

Answer (score 1):

TP-LINK TL-WN821N just works out of the box on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-24-generic-pae #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 10:47:59 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04 LTS"
```